# Accurate way to detect the main frequence of a sound file using NAudio

Tags: c#, fft, frequency, naudio

I am a beginner in NAudio programming and i have this problem. I have a lot of sound files which are used in a project i am working on. These files are a different frequency wave sounds which starts from 20 Hz to 20kHz. I searched online and i found the NAudio library to be -may- helping me to do the Recording and the calculation which i need.

All what i need is a function which takes the stream from the mic (lets say for 5 second) and calculate the fundamental frequency and return it as a float. The input coming from the mic should be also a good source (not noisy) so we can say that this signal is going to be good. Is that possible with NAudio library or i should use another library ? - Is there any ready C# samples for this ?

Thanks in advance for help.

--
Regards,
Ahmad